# How does wglGetProcAddress/glXGetProcAddress communicate with a graphics driver?

Tags: linux, winapi, opengl, driver

When I build an OpenGL application on Windows 10 I have to link to `opengl32.lib`. I use GLEW for loading OpenGL functions.  GLEW internally uses `wglGetProcAddress()`.  `opengl32.lib` provides support only for OpenGL 1.1.  How does `opengl32.lib` work when `wglGetProcAddress()` asks for some newer OpenGL functionality?  Does it act as a proxy and communicate with a graphics driver, for example OpenGL nvidia library?

Does it work the same way on Linux?

Comment: `wglGetProcAddress` presumably uses a scheme based on runtime-dynamic linking. Runtime-dynamic linking doesn't rely on import libraries, and queries the implementing modules for exported symbols.

Comment: I only link to opengl32.lib/dll. Does opengl32.dll link to propietary driver ? (for example nvidia)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows you have a so called OpenGL ICD (= Installable Client Driver). Essentially for every function that the OpenGL-1.1 specification defines this ICD provides an implementation proper that's passed through to by `opengl32.dll`, based on the currently active OpenGL context (i.e. you can have multiple ICDs installed, serving different OpenGL contexts within the same program).

The `wglGetProcAddress`  function is part of that set, which is the reason, why you've to load extending/newer functions for each context separately on Windows. So essentially when you call `wglGetProcAddress` it will just call the actual `...GetProcAddress` of the ICD.

On Linux we never had the concept of ICDs. A couple of years ago we finally got GLvnd (GL vendor neutral dispatch) which essentially gives Linux an ICD like mechanism. However the GLX specification clearly states, that the addresses obtained through `glXGetProcAddress` are invariant and identical for all OpenGL contexts. That means, that it's the OpenGL implementation's task (and not the intermediary layer between) to dispatch functions based on the context. The Mesa developers describe it here: https://docs.mesa3d.org/dispatch.html

In short: It's a mess.